# WrapPanel.Children.Add(): System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WrapPanel in a Windows Phone (7.1) Solution, where I add and delete cyclic user controls. Most time it work but sometimes I get the following error:

```
"The parameter is incorrect. "
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, CValue value)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddDependencyObject(DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Add(UIElement value)
at MyProject.Pages.DashboardPage.RefreshTiles()
```

I don't get this error reproduced, it just pops up sometimes. I noticed, that when I delete the whole WrapPanel and create a new the error never pop up. Thus it's seems to be some problem with deleting and adding items.
Here's my code:

```
private void RefreshTiles()
{
    wrapPanelRooms.Children.Clear();

    foreach (Room room in Data.Inst.Rooms)
    {
        ControlRoomTile newTile = new ControlRoomTile{...};
        newTile.MouseLeftButtonUp +=
            (sender, e) =>
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(
                new Uri("/Pages/RoomDetailPage.xaml?id=" + ((ControlRoomTile)sender).Id, UriKind.Relative));
        try
        {
            this.wrapPanelRooms.Children.Add(newTile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff") + " UI: RefreshTiles ERROR1");
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone knowing a fix for that?

Comment: I have seen this error before. All I can remember is that I stopped creating unique names for the elements, which probably did the trick. In your `ControlRoomTile` constructor, do you add unique names to the `UIElement` i mean the `x:Name` property? If you do, try commenting that part out.

Comment: In my ControlRoomTile.xaml I defined x:Name="userControl". When I initialize a new Instance of that I don't add a unique name.

Comment: Remove all `x:Name` attributes from your `ControlRoomTile.xaml` file.

Comment: How should I mange bindings without x:Name? example: <Grid Width="170" Height="170" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=userControl}">